# Mysql join three tables (2 of them similar)

Tags: mysql, join

my **customer table**

```
id | name
==========
1  | mick
2  | george
3  | john
```

**bakery transactions**

```
id | customer | type    |  amount | date
============================================
1  | 3        | bread   |       1 | 2016/03/10 10:00
2  | 1        | bread   |       2 | 2016/03/10 11:00
3  | 1        | baguette|       1 | 2016/03/10 11:00
4  | 2        | bread   |       2 | 2016/03/11 09:00
5  | 3        | cookie  |       5 | 2016/03/11 09:30
```

**greengrocery transactions**

```
id | customer | type    |  amount | date
============================================
1  | 1        | banana  |      1  | 2016/03/10 08:00
2  | 1        | apple   |      3  | 2016/03/10 08:00
3  | 1        | orange  |      5  | 2016/03/10 14:00
4  | 3        | apple   |      8  | 2016/03/11 09:30
5  | 1        | apple   |      8  | 2016/03/12 09:30
```

Is it possible to get customer transactions by date from these transaction tables by the customer?

More specific, I want to get customer Id:1 transactions, ordered by date;

This is **what I want.**

```
Id| transactionType|customer | type    |  amount | date
=====================================================================
1 |  greengrocery  |       1 | banana  |      1  | 2016/03/10 08:00
2 |  greengrocery  |       1 | apple   |      3  | 2016/03/10 08:00 
2 |  bakery        |       1 | bread   |      2  | 2016/03/10 11:00
3 |  bakery        |       1 | baguette|      2  | 2016/03/10 11:00 
4 |  greengrocery  |       1 | orange  |      5  | 2016/03/10 14:00
5 |  greengrocery  |       1 | apple   |      8  | 2016/03/12 09:30
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: first tried union then a query like  "left join bakery left join greengrocery where customerId = 1" and got a very unnecessary(cartesian for join) results.

Comment: post whatever you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need two joined queries unioned together, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.id,'bakery' as TransType,s.id as customer,t.type,t.amount,t.date
    FROM customer s
    INNER JOIN bakery t ON(s.id = t.customer)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id,'greengrocery' as TransType,s.id as customer,t.type,t.amount,t.date
    FROM customer s
    INNER JOIN greengrocery t  ON(s.id = t.customer)) tt
WHERE tt.customer = 1
order by tt.date
```

Basically, you don't even need to select from customer because your are not using the name value, so it can be done like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.id,'bakery' as TransType,t.customer as customer,t.type,t.amount,t.date
    FROM bakery t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id,'greengrocery' as TransType,t.customer as customer,t.type,t.amount,t.date
    FROM  greengrocery t) tt
WHERE tt.customer = 1
order by tt.date
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I want

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off having one table for transactions with a category field

```
id | category_id | customer | type    |  amount | date
============================================
1  |     1        |  3      | bread   |       1 | 2016/03/10 10:00
```

And then a category table like:

```
id | category_name | 
====================
1  |    bakery
```

You can then do a join like so:

```
SELECT transactions.id, category_name AS transactionType, customer.name, transactions.type, tranasactions.amount, transactions.date
FROM transactions
LEFT JOIN categories ON transactions.category_id=categories.id
LEFT JOIN customers ON transactions.customer=customer.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION ALL to generate the rows and use a variable to generate the new id.

```
SET @id = 0;
( SELECT @id:=@id+1 id, 'bakery', customer, type, amount, date 
  FROM bakery_transactions 
  WHERE customer = 1 )
 UNION ALL
( SELECT @id:=@id+1 id, 'greengrocery', customer, type, amount, date 
  FROM greengrocery_transactions 
  WHERE customer = 1 )
ORDER BY date
```